# Complex query for Elasticsearch to count the number of document according to different time

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have the data like following:

```
deviceId time        status
001      Nov.1 9:37  ok
001      Nov.1 19:02 fail
001      Nov.2 8:46  ok
001      Nov.3 10:59 fail
001      Nov.3 21:19 ok
002      Nov.1 9:37  ok
003      Nov.1 9:37  fail
003      Nov.3 2:18  ok
003      Nov.3 11:55 fail
003      Nov.3 15:11 ok
004      Nov.1 9:37 fail
```

I'd like to obtain the result like following (getErrorCountFrom([001, 002, 003])):

```
time          error(how many fail devices in this time)
Nov.1 10:00   1
Nov.1 22:00   2
Nov.2 10:00   1
Nov.2 22:00   1
Nov.3 10:00   0
Nov.3 22:00   0
```

Is it possible to query from Elasticsearch to get this result?

[image: the example diagram]

Answer (score 2):

This is strictly not "search" but you want aggregated results (bucketing by time the number of errors).

So, you need to use an aggregation. Specifically, the [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html)

The following should be close to what you want (depending on your Elasticsearch version, and mappings).

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "fail"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hourly_count": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "1h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. However, is date_histogram looking the timestamp back to the before? For example, the status at Nov.2 22:00 for 001 is ok (from Nov.2 8:46) and for 002 is ok (from Nov.1 9:37) and for 003 is fail (from Nov.1 9:37).

Comment: I don't understand. This query will provide a count for all documents, for each hour, that have the `status: fail`. What other context do you require?

Comment: I need to check the number of error devices twice a day: 10:00 and 22:00. Actually, there is no documents at 22:00 on Nov2 and I need to speculate the status from these documents. For example, 003 is marked as fail due to Nov.1 9:37 so that the number of error devices at 22:00 on Nov2 should be 1 instead of 0.

Comment: >"For example, 003 is marked as fail due to Nov.1 9:37 so that the number of error devices at 22:00 on Nov2 should be 1 instead of 0." So you want to pull forward different date times? You can simply do a range agg and count all failures that occurred between two date ranges if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I need to look forward to the closest document to determine the status for that device at certain time, and output it like date_histogram (every 1 hour or 12 hour). How can I achieve it in the Elasticsearch?

Comment: ", I need to look forward to the closest document to determine the status for that device at certain time," This doesn't make sense as the "closest" document could be days in the future. What are the time constraints for considering something failed? `date_histogram` can have any time interval you want. But, if there is no knowledge of "this could fail at any time in the future", I am not sure what you want.

Comment: I insert the diagram in the question. As mentioned, the dataset in the elasticsearch represents the status changed (green: ok, red: fail). What I want to get is the fail counts twice a day as the result in the bottom of the diagram. If use your query, the hourly_count between Nov.2 10:00 to Nov.2 22:00 would be 0 cause no documents in this period.